# Como sobrepor um JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

A tela principal do sistema que estou desenvolvendo abre com um `JInternalFrame` de boas vindas automaticamente, e nele está contido alguns botões para cadastro, agenda etc...

Porém, quando eu clico em algum botão para chamar outro `JInternalFrame` (*cadastro ou agenda*), ele fica por trás, e só aparece os `JTextFields` por cima.

Quero saber a forma de tratar isso, como fazer a hierarquia destes `JInternalFrame` para que sobreponha os outros quando clicar no mesmo...

Para facilitar a explicação, vamos supor que eu tenha o `JInternalFrameBemVindo`(que abre automaticamente com a tela principal) e um `JInternalFrameCadMedico`(que abre depois de clicar no botão contido na tela principal)

[image: print do erro]

Eis o código da tela principal:

```
public class Tela extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Tela() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

    jButton1.setText("Chamar outra tela");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
    jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
    jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jInternalFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(192, 192, 192)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 211, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(209, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jInternalFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(112, 112, 112)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 104, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(150, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(107, 107, 107)
            .addComponent(jInternalFrame1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(78, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jInternalFrame1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(68, 68, 68))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    NewJInternalFrame tela = new NewJInternalFrame();
    getContentPane().add(tela);
    tela.setVisible(true);

}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Tela().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

E o código do `JInternalFrame` que é chamado e "deveria" sobrepor o `JInternalFrame` que está contido na tela do código anterior (ele é chamado para ser visível quando o botão é pressionado):

```
public class NewJInternalFrame extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

public NewJInternalFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

    jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");

    jLabel3.setText("jLabel3");

    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

    jTextField2.setText("jTextField1");

    jTextField3.setText("jTextField1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(260, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(150, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Adicione a imagem diretamente aqui, e também o trecho problematico do código, para que seja possivel simular o problema.

Comment: @diegofm Pronto! Já o trecho problemático eu não tenho certeza, então coloquei o trecho de quando o botão é acionado...

Comment: O problema é que esse trecho apenas não é executável. Se possivel, adicione um [mcve] do seu código. Swing é importante simular antes pra não ter problema com resposta errada.

Comment: @diegofm Perdão pelos erros na postagem, é que sou novato no fórum! haha Mas está aí, tentei reproduzir o código completo, mínimo e verificável

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar [**`JInternalFrame`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html), você precisa adicioná-los dentro de um [**`JDesktopPane`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html). Por estar adicionando direto no `JFrame` é que seu código não funciona como esperado.

Altere sua tela adicionando um `JDesktopPane` preenchendo todo o espaço do `JFrame`, e vá adicionando os frames internos neste container, e não direto no JFrame.

Como seu código foi gerado pelo GUI-builder, eu não consegui alterar, mas fiz um exemplo baseado no seu código:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


/**
 *
 * @author diego.felipe
 */
public class JInternalFrameTest  {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public void createAndShowGUI() {

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Frame principal");
        frame.setSize(600, 500);
        //essas duas linhas são primordiais pro restante
        //do código
        JDesktopPane desk = new JDesktopPane();
        frame.setContentPane(desk);

        JInternalFrame mboxFrame = new JInternalFrame();
        JButton botao = new JButton("Chamar outra tela");
        botao.setSize(104, 104);

        botao.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MyInternalFrame tela = new MyInternalFrame();
                //repare que o internalFrame foi adicionado ao
                //desktoppane e não ao JFrame 
                desk.add(tela);
                tela.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        mboxFrame.setContentPane(botao);
        mboxFrame.setSize(300, 200);
        mboxFrame.setLocation(50, 50);
        mboxFrame.setVisible(true);
        //aqui a adição também foi feita
        //no desktoppane
        desk.add(mboxFrame);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

        public MyInternalFrame() {
            createGUI();
        }

        private void createGUI() {

            BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
            setLayout(boxLayout);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label1");

            JTextField campo = new JTextField("campo de texto");
            add(label);
            add(campo);
            pack();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tela.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JInternalFrameTest test = new JInternalFrameTest();
                test.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Resultado:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

---

**Referências úteis:**

- [How to Use Internal Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)
- [Adding Internal Frames to a JDesktopPane](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddingInternalFramestoaJDesktopPane.htm)

Comment: Resolvido! Agradeço!

Comment: @L.Maier disponha :)